# I have 2 snippets of code, one uses .then().catch and the other uses async/await. Are both snippets doing the exact same thing?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out whether I prefer `.then().catch` or `asyc/await` so I've been rewriting some of my code and seeing which way I like more. The issue is that I'm not exactly sure if the code behaves exactly the same way when using `.then().catch` and `asyc/await`. For example, here are 2 snippets of code:

```
        axios.post('/createRoom', room)
        .then((response) => {
            this.createRoomWindow = false
            this.servers[this.selectedServer].rooms.push(response.data.room)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

and

```
        try {
            let response = await axios.post('/createRoom', room)
            this.createRoomWindow = false
            this.servers[this.selectedServer].rooms.push(response.data.room)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

I'm curious whether or not these 2 pieces of code do the exact same thing or are there any differences which I just can't see myself. For example, it is my understanding that in the first snippet, `this.createRoomWindow = false` will only happen once I've received the response even though it has nothing to do with the response and doesn't require it.

I'm not sure if the `this.createRoomWindow = false` will execute before or after the POST request is finished in the second snippet. I know `this.servers[this.selectedServer].rooms.push(response.data.room)` will definitely execute after the POST request since it uses part of the response. Considering `this.createRoomWindow = false` doesn't have to wait for the POST request to be done, I assume JavaScript would execute it before the POST is finished.

Am I correct? And IF I am correct, how can I make sure that a piece of code executes only after the POST request if finished when using `async/await`?

Comment: they execute the same way. the async event mechanism is a little different, but the execution order is identical. with async / await, everything in the async function waits till the awaits are done. so no matter what, it's waiting till after the POST. it can't differentiate between what lines rely on the awaited value and those that don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are NOT the same. Await can be used together with a Promise (that is what's your first snippet is returning). From MDN:

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Most important:

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

While [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.

So take care because they are DEFINITELY NOT THE SAME. Please read provided docs very carefully.